# Mapping an entity to two other entites using hibernate and JPA

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following Database table structure

There is a parent entity "Shape" which is extended by two other entities "Rectangle" and "Circle". Now I have an entity "Color" that I need to associate with either "Rectangle" or "Circle".  There could be more entities extending from Shape which prevents me from associating the Color directly with Shape.

All entities Shape, Rectangle, Circle and Color have corresponding tables in the database.

Please help in coming up with appropriate annotations for mapping the structure in Java using hibernate and annotations.

Note that I am not allowed introduce more tables into the database.

Comment: this is not any homework to be true.. the real problem with me is quite complex and i thought I would put it in a simpler way.. may be I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

introduce `colore_id` in RectangleTable and in `CircleTable` And use `@ManyToOne` to annotate the references in the two classes